# Mount WordPress named volume in subdirectory of NGINX container with docker-compose

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose

The following configuration correctly serves a WordPress instance. (Some unrelated config details omitted for brevity.)

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    links:
      - wordpress-1
    volumes:
      - wordpress-1_files:/var/www/html

  wordpress-1:
    image: wordpress:php7.3-fpm-alpine
    volumes:
      - wordpress-1_files:/var/www/html

volumes:
  wordpress-1_files:
```

**wordpress-1.conf**

```
server {
  server_name wordpress-1.com;
  root /var/www/html;

  index index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress-1:9000;
  }
}
```

However, I would like to mount the `wordpress-1_files` volume to a subdirectory (`/var/www/html/wordpress-1`) in the `nginx` container (so that I can serve multiple applications from the same NGINX proxy). The configuration below returns a `404` with a `File not found.` in the response body. This result occurs with either of the two `SCRIPT_FILENAME` lines in the `wordpress-1.conf` below.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    links:
      - wordpress-1
    volumes:
      - wordpress-1_files:/var/www/html/wordpress-1

  wordpress-1:
    image: wordpress:php7.3-fpm-alpine
    volumes:
      - wordpress-1_files:/var/www/html

volumes:
  wordpress-1_files:
```

**wordpress-1.conf**

```
server {
  server_name wordpress-1.com;
  root /var/www/html/wordpress-1;

  index index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/wordpress-1$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress-1:9000;
  }
}
```

When I inspect the NGINX `error_log` in `debug`, I see this:

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading
>   response header from upstream, client: 555.69.70.132, server:
>   wordpress-1.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://172.18.0.3:9000", host: "wordpress-1.com"

That leads me to believe that there is an issue with `SCRIPT_FILENAME`, but neither `/var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name` nor `/var/www/html/wordpress-1$fastcgi_script_name` seem to work.

**Question:**

How can I adjust my second pair of config files so that I can serve WordPress when mounting the WordPress volume to a directory other than `/var/www/html` in the `nginx` container?

Note: The above example is a slimmed-down, minimum example of the issue I am trying to resolve. The actual project I'm working on is over [here](https://github.com/collinbarrett/wp-host-on-containers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, turns out my testing was just not thorough enough (despite going at this for a few days off and on). The solution was in fact using:

`fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;`

This is because inside of the `wordpress:php7.3-fpm-alpine` image, that is the path where the WordPress files are located.

During my testing, I had forgotten to disable CloudFlare's caching which was sitting in front of my staging site. So, my tests were not always testing what I thought they were...

Comment: Did you find a way to change wordpress' default install location (`/var/www/html/`) to something else, thus avoiding this problem?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I tried. I think you could create your own Docker image that uses the official WordPress image as its base and move the files to the desired location. But, I haven't tried it.

Comment: Yeah that's actually an interesting idea... thanks.